# How to use Next.js Automatic Static Site Optimization and still export for Netlify?

Tags: next.js, netlify, static-site

I have been working on implementing some of the updates from [Next 9.3](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3). I have been moving from `getInitialProps` to `getServerSideProps` and noticed that my `exportPathMap` became unhappy with these pages becoming dynamic. Everything works fine running `next`, but when I go to run `next build && next export`, I run into some issues.

In the docs for [static html export](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) it states `If your pages don't have getInitialProps you may not need next export at all; next build is already enough thanks to Automatic Static Optimization.` I am able to get that to work happily with my new `getServerSideProps` calls when I run `next build && next start`. What steps do I need to take in order for that to also work with `next export` so I can deploy via Netlify. Here's an example of the error I am getting when I attempt to run `next export`

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/videos/[videos_title]". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error:
Error: Error for page /videos/[videos_title]: pages with `getServerSideProps` can not be exported. See more info here: https://err.sh/next.js/gssp-export
```

Comment: Facing the same issue here.. Can you also raise a bug/request in nextjs github page itself?

Comment: I believe it's not possible to deploy on Netlify while using getServerSideProps.

Comment: @Ganesh I think you're right. You can't use getServerSideProps with next export because next export exports the site as a static site.

Comment: I have provided ways of deploying NextJS SSR Applications. Do checkout and accept if that is helpful so that others can utilize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applications build with SSR cannot be deployed in Netlify or any other static hosting sites (Except Vercel, which supports NextJS SSR Deployment)

> When you go for SSR (using getServerSideProps), it's meaningless to
>   use the command `next export` since it will try to create static
>   content which is totally opposite to the SSR.

- One way of deployment is to run it in the Virtual Server (like EC2)
  by creating custom server.js file with proper routing configuration.
- Another easy & quick method is to use **Vercel** ***(Zeit
  formerly)*** for deployment of SSR implemented Applications where
  they handle it wisely

Vercel has poor documentation for deployment of SSR Applications. Luckily I've got the below information from the Support Team and requested them to update the documentation to elaborate more about the SSR Deployment in Vercel.

> When deploying in Vercel,

- Give Build Command as `next build` or `npm run build`
- Leave the Output Directory as **Empty**

NOTE: Application with custom server.js will not work properly in Vercel, in that case, go for Virtual Server (Like EC2)